# Accesing a credit card terminal

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to know if with POS for .NET v1.12 there is the ability to send to a credit card terminal the amount of what you want to charge the credit card and to have a event that throws the result back.

I am not interested to get the information from the credit card, maybe just the credit card no, but for now I just want to sent the amount.

I saw there is this class on the POS for .NET : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.pointofservice.cat(v=winembedded.11).aspx

Is this class to be used in accessing a CC terminal? has anyone use it to work with CC terminals?

In my country all of the merchants use this kind of terminals that are connected directly to the bank:

https://www.google.ro/search?q=credit+card+terminal&newwindow=1&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=Yxs3UqGZIMWqhAfs74HABA&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAQ&biw=1163&bih=853&dpr=1#facrc=0%3Bcredit%20card%20terminal%20png

Answer (score 0):

If your CC terminal has a compatible CAT Service Object then it should work.  Otherwise it won't.

In my experience in European countries, the CC terminals usually have a proprietary protocol and don't supply a UPOS CAT Service Object.

Comment: So what are u saying is that there is no way to use POS .NET to sent amount to a CC terminals, only using their sdk.

Comment: I'm saying if the CC terminal supplier doesn't provide you with a UPOS-compatible service object (and I don't know of any that do in the countries I've worked in), then you must use their proprietary protocol / sdk.